# So is the phone without BLE vulnerable before BlueBorne or not?

Tags: android, bluetooth, blueborne

> It is already known that BlueBorne poses no danger to Android-devices
>   using Bluetooth Low Energy. For other cases, there were updates that
>   were included in the September Android Security Bulletin.

My phone does not support BLE. - then it is vulnerable?

> Users of Android devices can check their gadgets for vulnerabilities through a  special application BlueBorne Vulnerability Scanner by Armis, already available in the Google Play catalog.

Checked through this scanner. I get that the phone is invulnerable. Confused...

Comment: It seems like you're misinterpreting the first quote as meaning that a phone without BLE must be vulnerable, while it's really only saying that phones with BLE are not vulnerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are confused.

It only attacks via Bluetooth, not Bluetooth Low Energy, but that info doesn't matter to you as your phone does not have BLE.

What matters is if the Bluetooth firmware and config are vulnerable.

The scanner says you aren't vulnerable, so you are probably not vulnerable.

Comment: _Probably_...In any case, just do not leave bluetooth on.